# Вывести числовой квадрат заданного размера

Tags: c

Что-то не так, можно подсказку?) Выводит правильно, только если ввожу 2.

Пример ввода

> 2

Пример вывода

> 1 2
>
> 3 4

Условие задачи:

Вывести числовой квадрат заданного размера.
Выведенные числа начинаются с единицы и постоянно увеличиваются.
В каждой строке числа разделены пробелами.
Размер считать с клавиатуры.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main() {  
    int total;  
    int temp = 1;

    scanf("%d", &total);
    printf("%d ", 1);

    for ( int i = 0; i < total; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
            temp += 1;
            printf("%d ", temp);
        }
        temp += 1;
        printf("%d\n", temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно быть

```
...
for ( int i = 0; i < total; i++ )
{
  for ( int j = 0; j < total; j++ )
  {
    temp++;
    printf("%d  ", temp);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Тогда будет выведено `total` чисел в строчку и `total` строчек. Итого - `total`*`total` элементов, что и требовалось.

Либо легко можно отделаться одним циклом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < total * total; i++)
{
  printf("%d ", i + 1);
  if (((i + 1) % total) == 0) printf("\n");
  // если вывели total элементов - перевод строки
}
```

P.S. `printf("%d ", 1);` перед циклами необходимо убрать. Это заведомо лишнее действие.

Comment: Спасибо,если убрать printf("%d ", 1) тогда начинает считать с 2х,
2 3 
4 5

Comment: Ну, а теперь скорректируйте выводимые значения =)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,дальше уже разберусь)

Comment: Если можно подскажите,к примеру если я ввиду 6 на выводе получу 

1 2 3 4 5 6

7 8 9 10 11 12

13 14 15 16 17 18

.....

то есть смещается,как сделать что бы числа были одни под другими?

Comment: Для этого нужно сделать две вещи:
1) определить сколько цифр будет в самом длинном числе;
2) изменить строчку вывода с `printf("%d", i + 1)` на `printf("%5d", i + 1)`. Теперь все будет выровнено по пять символов. Еще вариант - можно передавать кол-во символов для выравнивания как отдельный аргумент ф-ции: `printf("%*d", 5, i + 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Внутренний цикл тоже до total (границы обоих циклов д.б. одинаковые, тогда получится квадрат).

Comment: for ( int i = 0; i < total; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < total; j++ ) {
            temp += 1;
            printf("%d ", temp);
        }
        temp += 1;
        printf("%d\n", temp);
    }
если так то при вводе 2 
выводит 
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7

Comment: в цикле по i ничего печатать не надо - только переводить каретку

Comment: Не подходит.

Comment: printf("\n") - это и есть перевод каретки

Comment: Спасибо,я знаю за перевод каретки)

Answer (score 1):

Кому интересно конечное решение вот такое:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int total;

int temp = 0;

scanf("%d", &total);

for ( int i = 0; i < total; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < total; j++ ) {
        temp += 1;
        printf("%3d", temp);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить

```
   for ( int i = 0; i < total; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
            temp += 1;
            printf("%d ", temp);
        }
        temp += 1;
        printf("%d\n", temp);
    }
```

на

```
for ( int i = 0; i < total; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
        temp += 1;
        printf("%d ", temp);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Так пробовал, не подходит(